# How to include undefined in a return type only if an argument could be undefined using Exclude<>?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a function that takes `string` and returns `number` include `undefined` in the return type only if the argument included it.

Here's what I have (which I thought would work):

```
export function test<T extends string | undefined>(a: T)
  :Exclude<boolean | T, string> {
    if (a === undefined)
        return undefined;
    return true;
 }
```

I hoped that `Exclude<boolean | T, string>` would remove the `string` from the `string | undefined` leaving either `undefined` or nothing (depending on the supplied argument type) however this code does not type-check, it says:

> Type `'undefined'` is not assignable to type `'boolean | Exclude<T, string>'`.

Answer (score 12):

Unresolved conditional types (like `Exclude<boolean | T, string>` with `T` generic) are not often assignable.  The compiler doesn't really know how to determine if something is of such a type because it does not try to iterate through all possible instantiations of the generic `T` to see if the assignment is safe.  So in these cases you usually [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) that a value is that type, or you use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) so that the function implementation uses plain-old union types instead of conditional types.  Here's the assertion solution:

```
export function test<T extends string | undefined>(a: T): Exclude<boolean | T, string> {
  if (a === undefined)
    return undefined as Exclude<boolean | T, string>; // asserted
  return true;
}
```

And here's the overload solution:

```
export function test<T extends string | undefined>(a: T): Exclude<boolean | T, string>;
// overloaded
export function test(a: string | undefined): boolean | undefined {
  if (a === undefined)
    return undefined;
  return true;
}
```

As long as they work the way you want when you call them with concretely-typed values, then conditional types should behave how you expect:

```
const definitelyDefined = test("hey"); // boolean, okay
const maybeUndefined = test(Math.random()<0.5 ? "hey" : undefined); // boolean | undefined, okay
```

(As an aside, I'd probably render your return type as `boolean | (undefined extends T ? undefined : never)`:

```
export function test<T extends string | undefined>(
  a: T
): boolean | (undefined extends T ? undefined : never) {
  if (a === undefined)
    return undefined as (undefined extends T ? undefined : never); // asserted
  return true;
}
```

But that's just a matter of preference.)

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Nice, thanks! Is there a way to alias `(undefined extends T ? undefined : never)` somehow, since I actually have lots of functions I want to do this too (mostly there things that you pass a path and it returns a boolean, and I want to propagate undefineds for convenience)

Comment: Sure, you can make a type alias `type MaybeUndefined<T> = undefined extends T ? undefined : never` and then make `function test<T>(a: T): boolean | MaybeUndefined<T> {...}`.

Comment: When using assert solution the result of `test(undefined)` is still `boolean | undefined` not strictly `undefined`. So I ended up with overload solution..

Comment: Is there a solution to the type of `a` still being `undefined` in the `else` branch after having immediately checked whether it was `undefined`. Seems a bit strange...

Answer (score 8):

You could use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to achieve this. Start by making your function accept either type and return either type, then add overloaded definitions to restrict which parameter & return types can be used together.

```ts
function test(a: string): boolean;
function test(a: undefined): undefined;

function test(a: string | undefined): boolean | undefined {
  if (a === undefined)
    return undefined;

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Sure, but overloads are clunky and I was under the impression this is what `Exclude<>` would let me do. I guess my question is more about "why doesn't this code work as I expect" than "how can I do x" :)

Comment: Note that these overloads don't allow you to call `declare const maybeString: string | undefined; test(maybeString);`.  You'd probably want to add a call signature that allows `string | undefined` parameters also.